# View doesn't fill the whole screen

Tags: android

I'm having everything the same as in this sample in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/multi-tracker except my activity layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <be.citylife.communitypurchaseapp.view.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60">

        <be.citylife.communitypurchaseapp.view.camera.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </be.citylife.communitypurchaseapp.view.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sideContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My tablet is in landscape and I want that the cameraPreviewSource is always left and fills the whole screen in the height and then right off it I'm having a fragment that fills the rest.

This layout works except my previewsource doesn't fill the whole height. It has a black banner on it. Even my width is actually smaller than I want you can see this on the screenshot:

http://i61.tinypic.com/vctmw0.png

I played with the CameraSourcePreview with the width and height in the onLayout function but it doesn't help. I know on the preview that it does fill the screen to the bottom of the screen but on the tablet it isn't.

[image]lp.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

EDIT:

I think it has something to do with this:

```
  @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            if (size != null) {
                width = size.getWidth();
                height = size.getHeight();
            }
        }

        // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
        if (isPortraitMode()) {
            int tmp = width;
            width = height;
            height = tmp;
        }

        final int layoutWidth = right - left;
        final int layoutHeight = bottom - top;

        // Computes height and width for potentially doing fit width.
        int childWidth = layoutWidth;
        int childHeight = (int)(((float) layoutWidth / (float) width) * height);

        // If height is too tall using fit width, does fit height instead.
        if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
            childHeight = layoutHeight;
            childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
            getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, childWidth, childHeight);
        }

        try {
            startIfReady();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
        }
    }
```

That's the onlayout method off the CameraSourcePreview.

Comment: I have your same issue, a portion of the view is black when the camera is on. Did you find any fix for that?

Answer (score 5):

Comment or remove below lines from CameraSourcePreview and it should be fine. I was having same issue like you and it is solved now.

```
if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
    childHeight = layoutHeight;
    childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
}
```

Comment: Works for me! Not sure if there are any repercussions to doing this but will use for now

Comment: camera height is starched. any have solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

that should put it into fullscreen mode :D there are a bunch of other modes you can select from. if this doesnt work, remove the automatically generated

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




/** gets called when a Menu.onClick happens
 * 
 * @param item the ID of the clicked Item
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //TODO
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't help to solve my problem. The problem is on the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

Likely has something to do with the aspect ratio of the camera and how it draws into its container.

If the camera preview you're using maintains aspect ratio and fits the preview to the container, then you will definitely get black bars. This is because most cameras' sensors produce images that are designed to fit within a space relative to 1920x1080px (or a 16:9 aspect ratio box).

What you need, is for the extra space on the sides to be hidden and for the preview to fill based on height. That is, if you don't mind some of your image to be hidden from the user when previewing. It might not be possible to do this directly with the view you're using, but it should be relatively simple if you place your object into another layout container.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I need to wrap my layout with another layout in xml to accomplish this? Or what do you mean?